# How to make Debian bookworm prefer a newer font version whenever at least two versions of the same font are available?

Tags: fonts, truetype-fonts, fontconfig, debian-bookworm

For the sake of an example, consider two fonts files of the same font:

```
$ fc-scan /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/cour.ttf --format='%{family} %{fontversion}\n'
Courier New 184812
$ egrep -ao "Version [0-9]*\.?[0-9]*" /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/cour.ttf
Version 2.82
$ fc-scan /usr/local/share/fonts/a_link_to_a_folder_on_another_partition/cour.ttf --format='%{family} %{fontversion}\n'
Courier New 453509
$ egrep -ao "Version [0-9]*\.?[0-9]*" /usr/local/share/fonts/a_link_to_a_folder_on_another_partition/cour.ttf
Version 6.92
```

However, as of now, font-manager (started as a regular user or via `sudo`) shows the older version with 1249 glyphs (rather than the newer with 3763 glyphs) when being asked to present Courier New.
Links to folders on another partition are hypothetically subject to change or can break, so we would not like to reject/forbid the older font file on the root partition forever. Instead, we would like to allow for the newer font file to take precedence whenever both are available.

How to achieve this for all fonts (and not only for Courier New) in a concise, automatic way?